# What's the method for converting time from ms to days?

Tags: ruby, date, datediff

```
today = Time.now
  => 2014-01-12 22:24:39 -0500
future = Time.parse("01-03-2014")
  => 2014-03-01 00:00:00 -0500
"%2.f" % ((future - today)/60/60/24)
  => 47
```

How else can I get 47 days without having to do `/60/60/24` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compare two dates.

```
today = Date.today
future = Date.parse("01-03-2014")
days_diff = (future - today).to_i
```

Comment: That returns `4066457` ? You still have to do `(days_diff)/60/60/24` Which is what I am trying to avoid. (If possible)

Comment: Yes I just caught on. And it returns 48 days. I did not notice the subtle difference. Ty!